# Pronunciation of не

Tags: произношение

Is it always pronounced "nye"?

I've searched online but found no sources on it.

I hear it sometimes as *ни* and sometimes as *не*.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is не always pronounced nye?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Не* is proclitic, meaning that as far as pronunciation is concerned, it's a part of the word that follows it.

This means that *е* in it is subject to vowel reduction if not stressed, and hence is pronounced as *[ɪ]*.

The vowels in *не* in *не о то́м [nʲɪɐˈtom]* and *не́ о чем ['nʲeətɕɪm]* are pronounced differently.

Comment: Hi Quassnoi , I was hoping you could tell me where you got this information, i have been searching everywhere for a list of proclitic words in russain such as я не but i cannot seem to find anything in search.

Comment: Is there a way of knowing when a word is proclitic or is it just by memorizing that the word is proclitic?